# Why is MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type) defined to return an array of attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes, fieldinfo, getcustomattributes

```
public enum Animal
{
    [Description("King of jungle")]
    Lion= 1,

    [Description("Tallest there")]
    Giraffe = 2
}
```

Suppose I have the `FieldInfo`, I can go about it two ways:

```
//static one on 'Attribute' class
Attribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, 
                                                   typeof(DescriptionAttribute), 
                                                   false);
```

That's fine.

But the one below returns `[]` rather than `Attribute` ?

```
//instance one on 'MemberInfo` class
var attributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
```

This question is not really about MS' design choice. My question is should I be ever concerned about `field.GetCustomAttributes` returning multiple items for a specific attribute type? In what cases would that happen?

```
[Description("King of jungle")]
[Description("I'm a lion")]
Lion= 1
```

is never possible I guess. I think I should handle it when writing some reflection helper functions.

Comment: What about multiple attributes deriving from the same base type? One might query for all of those? For example XmlArrayItemAttribute.

Comment: @Alex I did some testing that way, and I still got only one attribute in array. Could you make it an answer with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes perfectly sense to return multiple items per attribute type. Think of attributes designed with a base class. Or attributes where you could supply multiple options/types by constructor.

One example is the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` See the MSDN:   [XmlArrayItemAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you want to restrict your attributes to be only used once, you could add the `allowmultiple:=False` flag to your `AttributeUsage`.

@Comment

The `DescriptionAttribute` has AllowMultiple:=False (Which is the default if you don't specifiy it - at least in VB.NET). To get the effect, create your own attribute derived from  `Attribute` and mark it with `AttributeUsage` where you set `AllowMultiple = True`.

Comment: That is, but which parent child pair has those attributes? I tried with some examples and did not get more than one in the array. Could you contrive an example to get the effect? May be I'm missing something. I will try to update the question with my example too.

Comment: Alex, brilliant, that edit made sense. Its about `AllowMultiple = True`, not inheritance thing. Could you remove that part related to `XmlArrayItemAttribute` and inheritance ? Or does it really have to do with the answer? I dont think so.

Comment: Now the big question is why is `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` defined at all! In my opinion that static function is unreliable simply, and plain ugly :)

Comment: @nawfal Inheritance and the Constructor type with XmlArrayItemAttribute are just two use cases where you want to retrieve multiple items per type.